# Chrome Notifications Developer mode was working in one Mac and now it stopped - code works on different Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Code was working on one 2020 Mac M1.

Now it doesn't work.

Copied the same code to another Mac 2016, and it works.

Same Chrome version.

Code is nothing weird.

So it's either an OS or Chrome setting?

```
            chrome.notifications.create({ 
                type: 'basic',
                iconUrl: 'icon.png',
                title: 'API Response',
                message: data
            });
```